# how retrieve google access token with asp 5 core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth

Hi I've not found the way to retrieve access token..

here's my code: (file startup.cs)
I've use mvc template from asp 5 (Vs 2015)

```
    services.Configure<GoogleAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
        options.AccessType= Configuration["Authentication:Google:AccessType"];

        options.Scope.Add(@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");

        //options.CallbackPath
    });
```

logging works fine, I can retrieve name and other useful information but not token or refresh token...

attention.. `GoogleAuthenticationOptions`is : Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google.GoogleAuthenticationOptions which is compatible with asp core, owin version is not.

thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services#GOOGLE

Comment: all can help me, thanks the problem at linked page is that use "provider" parameter in GoogleAuthentionOptions which is not available in Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google.GoogleAuthenticationOptions,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

One of the defining features of these authentication schemes is shared secrets that your application and the authenticating server must know. Today when developing applications it is common to accidentally check this into source control, which is problematic if you are using public source control like GitHub that allow anyone to see the secrets you checked in...

try this:

```
 var configuration = new Configuration();
 configuration.AddJsonFile("config.json");
 configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

look in the page for more info https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-Secret-Configuration